# Prove that set is closed.

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that set $A=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R^n}:x_1=x_2\}$ is closed in $\mathcal{R^n}$.

What would be the best approach? I've tried using condition considering sequences, but it doesn't seem right.

Comment: What's $l^2$???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$A:=\{(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in\mathbb{R^n} | x_1=x_2\}$$

Suppose

$$f : A \to \mathbb{R}$$

$${x:=(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)\in A} \mapsto x_1-x_2 $$

Now it's easy to see that:

$$\lim\limits_{h \rightarrow 0}{f(x+h)}=f(x) \quad \forall x \in A$$

Therefor our function $f$ is continuous.

If you watch closely you can see that every $x \in A$ maps onto $0$. This is a closed set in $\mathbb{R}$. Since we showed that the function is continous and the image set is closed, $A$ is closed aswell.
Q.E.D.

Comment: Why is $f$ well defined? What is the image of $(0,0,x_3,...,x_n)$ under $f$? [I think its better to define $f:(x_1,...,x_n) \to x_1-x_2$ then take the fiber of $\{0\}$].

Comment: You're completely right! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can use the fact that every finite dimensional subspace of a normed vector space over a complete field (I suppose $\mathbb{R}$ in your case) is closed. You can prove this noticing that every finite dimensional normed vector vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ is complete.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with $... l^2$ ?

Considering sequences is o.k.

Let $(a^{k})=((a_1^{k},..., a_n^{k}))$ a convergent sequence in $A$ with limit $a=(a_1,...,a_n)$.

Then we have $a_1^{k} \to a_1$ and  $a_2^{k} \to a_2$.

Since $a_1^{k} =a_2^{k} $ for all $k$, it follows that $a_1=a_2$. Hence $a \in A$.

Comment: I meant that there is standard euclidean norm.